# Use PHP to display the local IP address of the server

Tags: php, server, ip, apache2, lan

I need to display the address of the server by which it can be identified in LAN.
I tried using

```
echo $_SERVER["SERVER_ADDR"];
```

but this just returns 127.0.0.1 instead of 192.168.xx.xx.
How do i get the second one without the access to WWW?

Comment: well yeah, a server to itself is 127.0.0.1 ...

Comment: @treyBake I know it is, but I need a way to print it's LAN address. Im not asking why SERVER_ADDR isn't working, just stating that it doesn't

Comment: also, @treyBake to refer to the link you have posted, this is not a solution since my setup doesn't have access to www

Comment: you don't need www to access a website - just swap the url for yours?

Comment: I don't think you generally get what I'm trying to ask. I want the LAN address of my server. Not the external IP. You have posted a question which asks about external address and uses external sites as a solution. Why would it be a dupilcate?

Comment: The first "dupe" just returns 127.0.1.1, the second "dupe" is the address of the connecting host, not the server. I think you are trying to forcefully discredit this question. I know it's simple, but I can also search stackoverflow you know.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will help,

```
function getLanIP(){
    exec("ipconfig /all", $output);
        foreach($output as $line){
            if (preg_match("/(.*)IPv4 Address(.*)/", $line)){
                $ip = $line;
                $ip = str_replace("IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . :","",$ip);
                $ip = str_replace("(Preferred)","",$ip);
            }
        }
    return $ip;
}
```

**OR something like,**

```
$ip = getLanIP();
echo $ip;

<?php
function getLocalIp(){ 
     return gethostbyname(trim(`hostname`)); 
}
echo getLocalIp(); 
?>
```

Comment: code only answers ... ;)

Comment: Your answer pointed me to an even simpler approach, just use "hostname -I" (must include capital I), it outputs exactly what i need.

Answer (score 0):

Solution was simpler than I thought it would be.
Just use:

```
exec ("hostname -I", $ip);
echo $ip[0];
```